# DataAnnotations and RegularExpression in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I want to code for a regular expression for a string that will contain 4 digits eg, A1234 or AB1234
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression to match your final form that we hammered out in the comments below:

```
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\*]+)?[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: I mean only 4 digits suffixed. It could be ABC1234 as well.

Comment: Edited answer - is this what you need now?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, but this expression doesn't work as well. This is my code [RegularExpression(@"\d{4}$",ErrorMessage="ID must have atleast 4 digits")]

Comment: It give me an error message no matter what id I enter. Even if it is correct.

Comment: Can you try the revised version above?

Comment: That's not the exact error message in the attribute you quoted above - are you sure it's coming from this regular expression attribute and not elsewhere? Or is one a typo in your comment?

Comment: it is. I changed the error message to say "ID must have 4 digits"

Comment: OK, another attempt. If this fails, also try ^.*[0-9]{4}$

Comment: Ah, yes. It would do. Is there always a prefix to the four digits? Is 1234 valid or not?

Comment: there could be a prefix to the four digits. 1234 is valid

Comment: OK, try this version then. It ensures that if anything is before the four digits, the last character is a non-digit. Thus it WILL allow something like 12A1234, but not 12345...

Comment: No, I will get you the right solution. But to do this you need to specify the problem. Can you tell me exactly what is a valid ID? Is the prefix a number of capital letters only?

Comment: ok..any amount of alphabets in the prefix followed by only 4 digits.. could be A1234, AB1234, ABC1234, ABCD1234 etc. There can be only 4 digits suffixed to any amount of character(max string length 12). Hope that explains it.

Comment: examples of what are valid and not valid
1234 valid
A1234 valid
AB1234 Valid
Ab1234 valid
ab1234 valid
a*1234 valid
a*b1234 valid
1234A not valid
*1234 not valid
*a1234 not valid
A1234B not valid
12345 not valid
A12345 not valid

Comment: So, if there is a prefix, first character must be alphabetic, prefix can then contains alphabetic plus asterisk, then finally exactly 4 digits?

Comment: yes..if there is a prefix, first character must be alphabetic, prefix can then contains alphabetic plus special character, then finally exactly 4 digits

Comment: OK, Regex is in answer. If you need additional special characters, just add them where the asterisk is. You many need to escape with \ if they're Regex special characters.